# Python3 move mouse in DirectX games

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, directx

I'm trying to build create a script that does a few action inside an DirectX game.

I've got everything working exept for moving the mouse.

Is there any module avalable that can move the mouse, for windows (python 3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) once in Python 2.7. I just checked under Python 3.7 and it moves the cursor alright. Sample code from linked source:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Set pointer position
mouse.position = (10, 20)
print('Now we have moved it to {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Move pointer relative to current position
mouse.move(5, -5)

# Press and release
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

# Double click; this is different from pressing and releasing
# twice on Mac OSX
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)

# Scroll two steps down
mouse.scroll(0, 2)
```

Edit: Just successfully tested in a DirectX game.

Comment: I want to use this in an 3D third person game, I've tried this methode unfortunatelyit does not respond.

Comment: Which game exactly? Or which engine? Maybe I can help/test on my end.

Answer (score -1):

Use a freeware App called sikulix. It will do wonders for you

Comment: He is trying to code it himself. I think that this answer is a bit redundant in this situation :)

Comment: Will look into but I would prefer to not use other tools but pyhon.